# How to do permutation/ combinations of column for a dataset in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, combinations, permutation

I want to generate various combinations of two variables in the dataset and calculate multiple regression lines.

Specifically, in the current dataset each site has 4 replicates. The corresponding sp1 and sp2 column typically has a couple of NAs across the columns. Ultimately, I want to regress sp1 against sp2. So, I want to generate a data-set such that for each SITE, a non-NA from sp1 is paired with non-NA of sp2. Together, this will generate a unique combination to generate a unique data-set. Then, we do this for all other combinations. At the end of each data-set generated, I want to store the dataset in a master dataframe with reference to interaction number

Dataset looks like this

```
site <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6)
repl <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
sp.1 <- c(NA,1,NA,4,NA,6,7,NA,3,4,5,NA,NA,1,NA,4,NA,6,7,NA,3,4,5,NA)
sp.2 <-  c(2,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,7,8,5,1,NA,3,2,NA,1,NA,5,6,7,8,5,1,NA,3)
df.dummy <- data.frame(site, repl, sp.1, sp.2)
```

That looks like this

```
    site repl sp.1 sp.2
1    1   1   NA    2
2    1   2    1   NA
3    1   1   NA    1
4    1   2    4   NA
5    2   1   NA    NA
6    2   2    6    NA
7    2   1    7    7
8    2   2   NA    8
....
```

So, in combinations of dataset we may see are

```
      Iteration 1
       site sp.1  sp.2
        1    1     2
        1    4     1
        2    6     7
        2    7     8
    ....

      Iteration 2
       site sp.1  sp.2
        1    1     1
        1    4     2
        2    6     7
        2    7     8
    ....

    Iteration 3
       site sp.1  sp.2
        1    1     1
        1    4     2
        2    6     8
        2    7     7
    ....

    Iteration 4
       site sp.1  sp.2
        1    1     2
        1    4     1
        2    6     8
        2    7     7
    ....
```

Therefore the master-dataset with multiple iterations (`it`) looks like:

```
     it site sp.1  sp.2
      1  1    1     2
      1  1    4     1
      1  2    6     7
      1  2    7     8
       ....
      2  1    1     1
      2  1    4     2
      2  2    6     7
      2  2    7     8
    ....
      3  1    1     1
      3  1    4     2
      3  2    6     8
      3  2    7     7
    ....
      4  1    1     2
      4  1    4     1
      4  2    6     8
      4  2    7     7
    ....
    .....
```

Comment: what about `?expand.grid`?

Comment: This is so ugly I'm adding it as a comment, but:
`df.dummy %>% mutate(newcol = coalesce(sp.1,sp.2), newcol2 =
  coalesce(sp.2,sp.1)) %>% select(site,it,newcol,newcol2) %>% filter(!is.na(newcol))`

Actually, this is not producing the correct values. Am curious about the solution; this is much harder than it seemed.

Comment: @tpetzoldt expand.grid is giving me all possible combinations across all the rows. But I only want combinations for each site not for the entire dataset. And different combinations constitute a new iteration.

Comment: @user2619203 The error its throwing is that you are trying to select for "it" but it (or iteration) does not exist in the original dataset instead is added in each loop.

Comment: @Biotechgeek I added "it" as a variable in an earlier command. It just duplicates the "repl" column, so you can see the (incorrect) output if you switch "it" to "repl." Maybe experimenting with intermediate coalesce steps might make it clearer to you.

Comment: I think this is getting close:

`df.dummy %>% group_by(site) %>% fill(everything(),.direction='downup') %>%
  select(it=repl,site,sp.1,sp.2) %>% arrange(site) %>% as.data.frame`